# Testing Django 1.5 apps with custom user

Tags: python, django, django-nose

Getting the error

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
admin.logentry: 'user' has a relation with model su.SuUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.`
```

when I run `python manage.py test`.

su is my user app, and app is where most of the work is done.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    "su",
    "app",
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'su.SuUser'
```

**su/models.py**

```
class SuUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(_('User name'), max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'su'
```

**app/tests.py**

```
from django_nose import FastFixtureTestCase as TestCase

from nose.tools import assert_equals

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test.utils import override_settings

User = get_user_model()

@override_settings(AUTH_USER_MODEL='su.SuUser')
class TestApp(TestCase):
    ...
```

Any idea? `syncdb` works fine. Running the app works fine.

**EDIT 1**

Even if I try to skip the custom user such as

```
@skipIfCustomUser
class TestApp(TestCase):
    ...
```

still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix, but it may be a symptom of a bug. Previously, my directory structure looked like this:

```
root/
    su/
        su/
            views.py
            models.py (held SuUser)
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
            ...
        app/
            views.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            tests.py
```

on a whim, I broke out the user part into it's own app

```
root/
    su/
        su/
            views.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            wsgi.py
            ...
        suuser/
            views.py
            models.py (holds SuUser)
            urls.py
            ...
        app/
            views.py
            models.py
            urls.py
            tests.py
```

This works. After debugging, I found that the su "app" was never getting loaded into the app_store (django/db/models/loading.py). I haven't traced it back to see why or where or if it's by design. Anyone know?